# Just get list of files while doing 'Find in Files' in sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

I am doing a Find in Files option in sublime text 3 and just want the list of files. I do not want the the content where the selection is found.

I want to just compile a list of files where my search query is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should probably use something else to search.

If you're under *nix try

```
grep -rli 'my pretty awesome search' /path/to/search/
```

and it will search recursively for your string in this directory.

The parameters:

- r - recursive
- i - case insensitive
- l - only print out file names